# How to programmatically make NFC work when is screen off

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to enable or force NFC work while screen is off? 
There are some ways like downloading a nfc enabler apk or root the device but I want to make it in my application, not using another application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to enable or force NFC work while screen is off?

No, there is no way to do this. NFC is off by design when the screen is off, mainly to safe power.

Comment: Thank you. I read a lot about it and also test it and relaize that it does not work but I need a guru approval :)

Comment: @ondermerol I've spend three years reading and porting the android NFC service code. I hope that's guru enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it provided you have access to the firmware code. Once you enable it in firmware, you need to define your flag in NFCService and enable NFC working even when screen is off. I have seen few devices having NFC working even when powered off but that is card emulation mode. So it is possible.

Comment: Will Google reject the app if we do that?

Comment: This is quite tricky question. Well the few devices which supported NFC working even when powered off(card emulation mode) had compliance with Softcard wallet previously known as ISIS Wallet and not Google. So if you go by this, if you do this feature, definitely Google would reject it. As you know this Softcard wallet is joint ventue of AT&T,verizon and T-Mobile, they have their own features and is restricted from others unlike Google. But irrespective of all these proprietaries, I can say NFC can work even when phone is off or screen locked.

Comment: @AngryWolf123 True, but in this cases only card emulation from the SIM card is allowed. This works entirely without help from the main CPU. Only the NFC Controller and the SIM card is involved in that kind of operation.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck Yeah true in phone power off state, NFC Chip only acts as passive device with either SIM/eSE access but the main CPU will be off. So you will have only card emulation working. but in case of screen off, you have the main CPU running. So you can access it from NFC Chip and make NFC work even tag read/write,P2P along with card emulation. This can be achieved only if changes are made in NFC Chip firmware and also in the kernel of main CPU...